# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: java, selenium, nosuchmethoderror, webdriverwait

I hit the following error whenever I try to use `wait.until(ExpectedConditions)` in my project:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Sample code which I see issue with :

```
public static void clickSearch(WebDriver driver,By by, int timeout){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    WebElement webElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    webElement.click();
}
```

AND

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(waitSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
          return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
      }
});
```

I have got the following libraries:

```
activation.jar
byte-buddy-1.8.3.jar
cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
commons-exec-1.3.jar
commons-io-2.5-javadoc.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar
commons-lang3-3.5.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dsn.jar
gson-2.8.5.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
http-client-6.6.0.5.jar
httpclient-4.5.5.jar
httpcore-4.4.9.jar
httpmime-4.5.5.jar
imap.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.1.jar
jackson-core-2.9.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.1.jar
java-client-3.3.0.jar
jaxen-1.1.6.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar
jcommander-1.72.jar
jna-4.4.0.jar
json-20151123.jar
jsr305-3.0.2.jar
junit-4.12.jar
jxl-2.6.12.jar
mail.jar
mailapi.jar
netty-3.5.7.Final.jar
ojdbc6.jar
okio-1.15.0.jar
pm-webdriver-6.6.0.5-javadoc.jar
pm-webdriver-6.6.0.5.jar
poi-3.17.jar
poi-examples-3.16.jar
poi-excelant-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
poi-scratchpad-3.17.jar
selenium-3.13\selenium-api-3.13.0.jar
selenium-3.13\selenium-java-3.13.0.jar
selenium-3.13\selenium-remote-driver-3.13.0.jar
selenium-3.13\selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar
selenium-3.13\selenium-support-3.13.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
smtp.jar
testng-6.14.2.jar
xml-apis-2.9.1.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
guava-26.0-jre.jar
```

We dont use Gradle/Maven in our project. We store the physical copy of these libraries in a location and use the same to build an executable jar using ANT script. And we execute the jar created by ANT script from command line:

```
java.exe -cp <ProjectJarName>;<Location of jar libraries> <Main class name with whole package>.
For eg : java.exe project.jar;C:\Libraries\*.jar java.main.Main
```

When I searched for the issue, the common answer I saw was adding latest guava jar which I have tried and it didn't solve the issue. Also in selenium forum in github, I see people solving the issue by making changes in pom.xml by changing the order which I don't think I have to do as I am not depending on maven.

Comment: So how do you compile your code?  If using an IDE, you could check what versions of the libraries are available to the IDE, since (if you are using one), it's not complaining about the unknown method that the execution complains about ...

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for that method is documented at: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#until-java.util.function.Function-

You're passing this https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html which extends `com.google.common.base.Function`.

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html says

> This interface is now a legacy type. Use java.util.function.Function
>   (or the appropriate primitive specialization such as ToIntFunction)
>   instead whenever possible. Otherwise, at least reduce explicit
>   dependencies on this type by using lambda expressions or method
>   references instead of classes, leaving your code easier to migrate in
>   the future.
>
> To use an existing function (say, named function) in a context where
>   the other type of function is expected, use the method reference
>   function::apply. A future version of com.google.common.base.Function
>   will be made to extend java.util.function.Function, making conversion
>   code necessary only in one direction. At that time, this interface
>   will be officially discouraged.

This suggests that either your JRE version or your library versions do not match. The error message you're getting says that you are passing a `com.google.common.base.Function` when the Javadoc for `until` says its argument should be a `java.util.function.Function`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your inputs. But I see that the com.google.common.base.Function extends java.util.function.Function. Following is the source code for the same. And IU am using the guava 26.0-jre jar where this change is available. [https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Function.java] Regarding JRE version, am in 1.8.0_131.

Comment: Since you are using JRE 1.8+ does the remark from the javadoc I linked and the source you posted help? `This interface is now a legacy type. Use {@code java.util.function.Function} (or the appropriate primitive specialization such as {@code ToIntFunction}) instead whenever possible.` the method you're trying to call expects the java.util.function.Function, the class you're passing says it's legacy and to use java.util.function.Function directly.